npm package is inferred to be any when referenced in main.ts
I created a custom npm package, which is a vue component.
Now I register this component globally in main.ts
But the editor inferred the type as any, which caused me to agonize when using components.
such as:

But I'm sure I've export this type
it look like this.

I tried adding type inference to global.d.ts
But the editor still prompts for any type
like this

Then I added volar to tsconfig.json

Still ineffective.

Those images must have hundreds of lines of code. As a normal rule, code is better posted in pre-formatted code blocks. That second image does not explain what is wrong with the exported type. I realise that there may discrepancies in the intellisense type-information but even they could be described in text rather than images. If intellisense is important to the question, could you specify what editor you are using?

First Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Second, I think this is a performance problem. In this playground: https://tsplay.dev/mAaGRm it seems to import as any then maxes out my CPU for a good 5 minutes, and then eventually resolves to the real type you want. Seriously, just wait, go get some coffee, take a walk, and when you come back you'll see the type.

As long as you can't reproduce the problem outside IDE, it's specific to it (VSC?) and the question doesn't make sense in general. Though the previous comment suggests it may be the problem with specific package
